# Sitecore 8 Installation Wizard in Development tools not working

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

After I installed sitecore 8, looks like I cant access installation wizard on development tools. All I can see is blank popup on all the browsers. I checked the log files and could not find anything related.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might help anyone with the same problem.

Sitecore is checking for Packages folder in Data Folder and failed. I don't understand why it can't create one(I checked the permissions all good.)Kind of bug in Sitecore 8 rev. 141212.

Once I created Packages folder, it's all good.

Comment: Thanks, exact same problem here!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to mongoDB not being setup properly.

See this article

http://sitecorejourney.nileshthakkar.com/2015/01/is-your-sitecore-8-stuck-up-while.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Feed:+SitecoreJourney+(Sitecore+Journey)&m=1

Comment: Thanks, but in my case MongoDb is configured correctly.

Comment: Ok, glad you got it sorted any how!